# How to change the behaviour of boost::variant operator <

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading, boost-variant

boost::variant defines operator < as follows:

> If which() == rhs.which() then: content_this < content_rhs, where
>   content_this is the content of *this and content_rhs is the content of
>   rhs. Otherwise: which() < rhs.which().

This is not what I want, because I'd like to fail some < comparison. For example, if I have a variant like this:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, double, std::string> DataType;
```

I want DataType(1) < DataType(2.0) to succeed but DataType(1) < DataType("2") to throw exception. Is there any way to achieve this?

I can't define

```
bool operator < (const Field& lhs, const Field& rhs)
```

because it will conflict with member operator < defined in variant class.

I can define a static_visitor, but I'd like to know if there's anyway to overload operator <.

Comment: Whatever you're using that compares those should have an optional custom comparator.

Comment: Sadly `variant::operator<` is a member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While wrapping your`DataType` inside another struct is surely the best solution, keep in mind that if you need a quick and dirty fix this works:

```
namespace boost
{
template<>
bool DataType::operator<(const DataType &) const
{   
    // impl
}
}
```

In C++11 you should be able to avoid the `namespace boost`.

Notice that this will break the ODR unless all your TU see this specialization before actually using it.

Comment: thanks, this works for me. However I do need namespace boost using gcc 4.8

Answer (score 1):

Create a `struct` containing nothing but a `boost::variant<Ts...> v;`.  Forward your constructors to it (possibly some manually).  Provide an `operator boost::variant<Ts...>()` optionally.

Have your own `<` on this `struct`.

Note, however, that `boost::variant` is intended to normalize the union.  It is supposed to be *normal* that some `variant`s are one type, and some are another type.

`<` is usually in `std::map` type containers or when sorting.  Having the keys be forced to be all the same type, or the sorted elements to be all the same type, seems like a bad idea.  The `variant` shouldn't contain both types if it isn't expected for any such `variant` to contain both types.

The places where `<` is automatically used all tend to expect an optional ordering predicate object.  I personally cannot think of why I'd ever use an exception throwing predicate object manually, which makes me leery of making yours the default.